# How can I add values from textfield when i press the button with not having all of the values

Tags: java, user-interface

im working on a java program using GUI, and i ran into a problem whenever i try to add the values from the text fields and one is missing it doesn't work and i get an error but if all of them are available i get the right answer, how can i add without having all the values?

```
JButton btnCheckOut = new JButton("CHECK OUT");
btnCheckOut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        double apples, strawberries, watermelon, tomatoe, carrot, beef, lamb, payment;

        apples = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
        strawberries = Double.parseDouble(textField_1.getText());
        watermelon = Double.parseDouble(textField_2.getText());
        tomatoe = Double.parseDouble(textField_3.getText());
        carrot = Double.parseDouble(textField_4.getText());
        beef = Double.parseDouble(textField_5.getText());
        lamb = Double.parseDouble(textField_6.getText());

        payment = (apples*8)+(strawberries*10)+(watermelon*14)+
                (tomatoe*5)+(carrot*6)+(beef*25)+(lamb*20);

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");

       textField_7.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(payment)));


    }
});
```

Comment: Simple: Firstly test of the JTextField is empty, and if so, then secondly if the data it holds parses well to a number. Only then use the value.

Comment: I would in your case create a method, e.g. `getDoubleValue( String txt )`, you can then use it for all items. Just like `getDoubleValue( textfield.getText() )`... this does check if txt is null, it will return 0. Otherwise the doublie parseDouble value of txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create e.g. getDoubleValue, which you apply to all your items when read. Simple as:

```
apples = getDoubleValue( textField.getText() );
...
...
```

then

```
public double getDoubleValue( String txt ) {
  double d = 0d;
  try {
    if( txt != null && !txt.isEmpty() ) {
      d = Double.parseDouble( txt );
    }
  } catch(Exception ex) {}
  return d;
}
```

(This will also take care for "dirty input", if the textfield does not contain a number it will set it to zero during parse).

Comment: perfect, it fixed my issue, i also have another question if you dont mind, how do i get the answer in a popup window?

Comment: I think you want something like JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Payment: " + df.format(payment) ); ?

Comment: A good style of dialogs, check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Answer (score 0):

Create an `IF` statement that sets the variables to `zero` if its respective TextField is empty, before you do the math operation.

```
if(textfield.getText().isEmpty())
{
    apples = 0;
}
```

Comment: I have set the values to zero once the textfield is made and when i reset because the IF statements didnt work for me, i still get an error with the IF statements

Comment: where did you place your `IF` statement? It needs to be after you PARSE the JTextfields or else your variables will be set to null if empty.

Answer (score 0):

When you make your textFields, initialize the text there to 0. Like

```
JTextField textField_1 = new JTextField("0");
```

Or, you could add

```
if(textField.getText() == ""){
   textField.setText("0");
}
```

For each text field before trying to parse to double.

Comment: setting the values to zero worked but i prefer if no numbers where showing at first.